# Angular generating an empty <option>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am generating some `<option>` elements using the `ng-repeat` directory. Using `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options` is intentional.

However, it generates an empty option in addition to the actual array. Here's the code:

```
<select name="type" class="form-control" ng-model="selected_type" ng-change="select_change()" >
    <option ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type.value}}">{{type.name}}</option>
</select>

$scope.types = [
    {value: '1', name: 'Sale'}, 
    {value: '2', name: 'Other'}
];
$scope.selected_type = $scope.types[0].value;
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/521/

Comment: Why is `ng-options` not appropriate for what you intend to achieve?

Comment: Removing ng-model from select fixed the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/529/

Comment: thsi actually worked
http://jsfiddle.net/aBPdv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle, using ng-options

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/527/

```
<select ng-model="selected_type" ng-change="select_change()" ng-options="c.name for c in types">
```

Then on script.js:

```
$scope.selected_type = $scope.types[0];
```

With that said, since you're just partly using angularjs you can just map the data in an array  before you actually post in say in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ng-model attributes on your option tag not on your select tag (use it where the ng-repeat is defined) like that :

```
<select ng-change="select_change()">
    <option ng-model="selected_type" ng-repeat="type in types" value="{{type.value}}">{{type.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Then change your

`$scope.selected_type = $scope.types[0].value;`

to

`$scope.selected_type = $scope.types;`

**But your ng-change will not work because no ng-model attribute is set so no ngModelController is assign to this element.**

So if you want to know when the value of the select change **you have to do a directive on the select element.**

For all these reasons **ng-options is always and i say always the right direction** for a select input usage.

Comment: This is in the right direction. But by doing this, I can't detect what option is chosen

Answer (score 1):

try ng-options instead of making options tag yourself:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selected_type" ng-change="select_change()" ng-options="type.value as type.name for type in types">
    </select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aBPdv/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.types = [
    {value: '1', name: 'Sale'}, 
    {value: '2', name: 'Other'}
    ];
    $scope.selected_type = $scope.types[0].value;
    $scope.select_change = function(x){
        alert($scope.selected_type);
    }
}
```